# Ubuntu 16.04 constant screen flickering

Tags: 16.04, screen

I installed 16.04 recently and every time I turn it on and I log in it flickers constantly. I can't connect to wifi but I can still access the terminal. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me also when I installed Ubuntu 16.04. Solved after updating the drivers[Screenshot of update page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZOzs.png)